# Drawing a path without setting a width and height in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a path inside a viewboxand canvas as such:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="MyViewBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="tick" 
                                               Width="146.768" Height="146.768" UseLayoutRounding="True" 
                                                                    Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                                    <Path x:Name="Path" Canvas.Left="4.12044" Canvas.Top="4.04301" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFF80000" Data="F1 M 4.28074,121.084L 4.15843,120.962C 4.40034,118.924 6.48998,117.557 7.9421,116.108C 10.772,113.284 13.6019,110.46 16.4318,107.637C 24.1129,99.9719 31.794,92.3074 39.4752,84.6428C 41.9008,82.2224 44.3264,79.802 46.752,77.3816C 47.1563,76.9782 47.5606,76.5748 47.9648,76.1714C 48.3691,75.768 48.7734,75.3646 49.1776,74.9613C 49.5819,74.5579 50.143,74.2658 50.3904,73.7511C 50.5336,73.4532 50.4055,73.0526 50.2299,72.7726C 49.9265,72.2889 49.4216,71.9658 49.0175,71.5624C 48.6134,71.159 48.2092,70.7556 47.8051,70.3522C 46.5927,69.142 45.3803,67.9318 44.1679,66.7216C 40.1265,62.6877 36.0852,58.6537 32.0438,54.6197C 25.9818,48.5687 19.9197,42.5177 13.8577,36.4668C 11.837,34.4498 9.81633,32.4328 7.79565,30.4158C 6.58325,29.2056 5.06703,28.2374 4.15843,26.7852C 4.04955,26.6112 4.20685,26.3775 4.23105,26.1737C 4.25526,25.9698 4.18553,25.73 4.30367,25.5621C 4.62703,25.1027 5.10008,24.7694 5.49829,24.3731C 5.89649,23.9767 6.2947,23.5803 6.6929,23.184C 8.28572,21.5985 9.87855,20.013 11.4714,18.4276C 14.657,15.2567 17.8427,12.0857 21.0283,8.91483C 22.6211,7.32936 23.8951,5.34012 25.8068,4.15845C 26.5968,3.67004 27.5839,4.85898 28.24,5.51649C 28.6434,5.92078 29.0468,6.32503 29.4502,6.72931C 29.8536,7.13358 30.257,7.53784 30.6604,7.94211C 33.8876,11.1763 37.1148,14.4104 40.342,17.6446C 47.6031,24.9215 54.8643,32.1983 62.1255,39.4752C 64.5459,41.9008 66.9662,44.3264 69.3866,46.752C 69.79,47.1563 70.1934,47.5606 70.5968,47.9648C 71.0002,48.3691 71.4036,48.7734 71.807,49.1776C 72.2104,49.5819 72.5025,50.143 73.0172,50.3904C 73.3151,50.5337 73.7157,50.4056 73.9957,50.2299C 74.4794,49.9265 74.8025,49.4216 75.2059,49.0175C 75.6093,48.6134 76.0127,48.2092 76.4161,47.8051C 76.8195,47.401 77.2229,46.9968 77.6263,46.5927C 80.8534,43.3596 84.0806,40.1265 87.3078,36.8934C 94.569,29.619 101.83,22.3446 109.091,15.0701C 111.512,12.6453 113.932,10.2205 116.352,7.79567C 117.563,6.58325 118.531,5.06705 119.983,4.15845C 120.763,3.67059 121.746,4.84642 122.395,5.49829C 122.792,5.89648 123.188,6.29471 123.584,6.6929C 123.981,7.09113 124.377,7.48932 124.773,7.88753C 127.152,10.2768 129.53,12.666 131.908,15.0552C 134.286,17.4445 136.664,19.8337 139.043,22.2229C 139.439,22.6211 139.835,23.0193 140.232,23.4175C 140.628,23.8157 141.024,24.2139 141.421,24.6121C 142.04,25.2343 142.971,26.3126 142.465,27.0298C 141.477,28.4297 140.039,29.4502 138.826,30.6604C 136.401,33.0808 133.975,35.5012 131.549,37.9216C 123.868,45.5862 116.187,53.2507 108.506,60.9153C 105.676,63.7391 102.846,66.5628 100.016,69.3866C 99.612,69.79 99.2077,70.1934 98.8034,70.5968C 98.3992,71.0002 97.9949,71.4036 97.5906,71.807C 97.1864,72.2104 96.6253,72.5025 96.3778,73.0172C 96.2346,73.3151 96.3627,73.7157 96.5384,73.9957C 96.8418,74.4794 97.3466,74.8025 97.7508,75.2059C 98.1549,75.6093 98.559,76.0127 98.9632,76.4161C 99.3673,76.8195 99.7714,77.2229 100.176,77.6263C 103.409,80.8534 106.642,84.0806 109.875,87.3078C 117.149,94.569 124.424,101.83 131.698,109.091C 134.123,111.512 136.548,113.932 138.973,116.352C 140.185,117.563 141.701,118.531 142.61,119.983C 143.098,120.763 141.922,121.746 141.27,122.395C 140.872,122.792 140.474,123.188 140.075,123.584C 139.677,123.981 139.279,124.377 138.881,124.773C 136.492,127.152 134.102,129.53 131.713,131.908C 129.324,134.286 126.935,136.664 124.545,139.043C 124.147,139.439 123.749,139.835 123.351,140.232C 122.953,140.628 122.554,141.024 122.156,141.421C 121.534,142.04 120.456,142.971 119.738,142.465C 118.339,141.477 117.318,140.039 116.108,138.826C 113.687,136.401 111.267,133.975 108.847,131.549C 101.182,123.868 93.5176,116.187 85.853,108.506C 83.0292,105.676 80.2054,102.846 77.3816,100.016C 76.9782,99.612 76.5748,99.2077 76.1714,98.8035C 75.768,98.3992 75.3646,97.9949 74.9612,97.5906C 74.5579,97.1864 74.2658,96.6253 73.7511,96.3778C 73.4532,96.2346 73.0526,96.3627 72.7726,96.5384C 72.2889,96.8418 71.9658,97.3466 71.5624,97.7508C 71.159,98.1549 70.7556,98.559 70.3522,98.9632C 68.3352,100.984 66.3182,103.005 64.3012,105.025C 58.2503,111.087 52.1993,117.149 46.1483,123.211C 41.7109,127.657 37.2736,132.102 32.8362,136.548C 31.626,137.76 30.4158,138.973 29.2056,140.185C 28.8022,140.589 28.3988,140.993 27.9954,141.397C 27.592,141.802 27.2693,142.307 26.7852,142.61C 26.6112,142.719 26.3775,142.561 26.1737,142.537C 25.9698,142.513 25.7301,142.583 25.5621,142.465C 25.105,142.143 24.7739,141.673 24.3798,141.277C 23.9857,140.881 23.5916,140.485 23.1975,140.089C 21.6211,138.505 20.0447,136.921 18.4683,135.338C 13.7391,130.586 9.00994,125.835 4.28074,121.084 Z "/>
                                </Canvas>
                            </Viewbox>
```

Up top I have had to define the width and height of the path. I was just wondering, is there a way I can not do that and simply allow silverlight to determine the width and height of the path from the canvas? Or perhaps define an explicit width/height like say 100,100 and force the inner path to draw to that. Currently the viewbox scales the path down to fit inside its parent grid and itw ould be ideal if the canvas could set the paths width and height such that it would fit.

I guess this sin't that important since I can always just keep defining width and height but I figure if I can make the xaml simpler I should try..

Ricks idea to use grids instead has worked quite well for the xaml above, however in this case:

```
 <Viewbox Visibility="Visible" x:Name="tickbox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Path x:Name="Path"  Canvas.Left="1.61674" Canvas.Top="423.576" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFF8F8F8" Data="F1 M 2.24249,423.576C 7.49307,425.327 9.74263,431.733 13.154,436.091C 15.8873,439.583 19.0756,442.697 21.9145,446.103C 32.7198,459.07 43.6481,471.933 54.4535,484.9C 75.4173,510.056 95.8553,535.67 115.503,561.867C 124.758,574.207 133.338,587.124 140.729,600.664C 143.154,605.107 144.567,610.072 147.143,614.43L 2.24249,615.056L 1.61674,614.43L 2.24249,423.576 Z "/>
                                    <Path x:Name="Path_0"  Canvas.Left="1.12545" Canvas.Top="0.352791" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF00B800" Data="F1 M 108.62,340.977C 110.289,341.095 111.957,341.212 113.626,341.329C 115.295,341.447 117.329,340.632 118.632,341.681C 120.441,343.139 120.731,345.827 121.78,347.9C 122.83,349.973 123.576,352.229 124.929,354.118C 128.431,359.01 131.833,363.984 134.941,369.136C 135.843,370.632 137.378,371.639 138.597,372.891C 139.816,374.142 141.325,375.166 142.254,376.645C 149.841,388.724 160.409,399.022 171.821,407.581C 178.232,412.389 185.453,416.769 193.305,418.375C 194.834,418.688 196.364,419.001 197.894,419.313C 199.423,419.626 200.958,420.592 202.482,420.252C 208.089,419.002 209.103,410.82 211.735,405.715C 217.912,393.732 223.858,381.619 230.524,369.901C 250.245,335.235 270.6,300.927 291.386,266.889C 316.703,225.431 344.166,185.23 373.312,146.369C 401.52,108.759 429.274,69.7278 465.102,39.288C 476.756,29.3865 488.046,18.5793 501.591,11.4812C 521.775,0.903687 546.274,0 569.058,0.438171C 578.918,0.627808 588.778,0.817383 598.639,1.00702C 607.812,1.18341 618.298,2.96027 624.863,9.36926C 629.283,13.6833 627.618,21.5565 627.366,27.7272C 627.132,33.4841 629.23,39.8399 626.662,44.9979C 622.944,52.4679 613.913,55.7723 607.342,60.9154C 593.594,71.6764 582.225,85.1784 570.041,97.6826C 542.594,125.851 517.912,156.713 494.473,188.295C 483.079,203.646 470.964,218.612 461.504,235.226C 460.778,236.499 459.444,237.312 458.414,238.355C 457.384,239.397 456.101,240.24 455.324,241.483C 406.922,318.927 357.946,396.555 319.232,479.268C 305.617,508.355 291.001,537.079 279.821,567.186C 276.698,575.597 273.356,583.97 269.164,591.903C 268.672,592.834 268.877,593.989 268.734,595.032C 268.59,596.075 268.649,597.166 268.303,598.161C 266.868,602.294 264.733,606.157 263.206,610.258C 262.611,611.858 262.881,614.173 261.42,615.056C 259.68,616.107 257.354,615.034 255.321,615.023C 253.288,615.012 251.255,615.001 249.222,614.99C 247.189,614.979 245.156,614.968 243.123,614.957C 228.892,614.88 214.661,614.803 200.43,614.726C 188.232,614.661 176.034,614.595 163.836,614.529C 161.803,614.518 159.77,614.507 157.737,614.496C 155.704,614.485 153.671,614.474 151.638,614.463C 149.605,614.452 147.267,615.501 145.539,614.43C 143.726,613.306 143.512,610.676 142.498,608.798C 141.485,606.921 140.471,605.044 139.458,603.167C 135.869,596.52 131.694,590.207 127.744,583.768C 114.001,561.363 97.8589,540.467 81.4389,519.942C 64.5882,498.878 47.396,478.089 30.1275,457.367C 23.1174,448.955 15.9782,440.651 8.85197,432.337C 7.06942,430.257 4.67798,428.761 2.86824,426.705C 2.43244,426.21 2.45108,425.454 2.24249,424.828L 1.61674,424.202C 1.83836,420.031 0,415.187 2.2816,411.687C 3.04422,410.517 4.77156,410.423 6.01655,409.79C 7.26153,409.158 8.64849,408.75 9.75149,407.894C 16.3236,402.792 22.8529,397.608 29.7755,392.993C 30.4704,392.53 31.5835,393.339 32.2785,392.876C 34.2191,391.582 35.3438,389.281 37.2845,387.987C 40.4037,385.907 44.1772,384.943 47.2965,382.864C 56.7196,376.581 65.4063,369.239 74.8294,362.957C 75.5244,362.494 76.6375,363.303 77.3324,362.84C 79.2731,361.546 80.3978,359.245 82.3384,357.951C 85.4577,355.871 89.2312,354.907 92.3504,352.828C 94.2911,351.534 95.4158,349.233 97.3564,347.939C 101.029,345.491 106.136,344.626 108.62,340.977 Z "/>
                                    <Path x:Name="Path_1"  Canvas.Left="1.61674" Canvas.Top="0.569702" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFF8F8F8" Data="F1 M 2.24249,0.569702L 538.51,1.19543C 525.297,4.70508 511.299,7.2359 499.713,14.4926C 462.987,37.4965 433.692,71.506 407.063,105.696C 387.819,130.404 368.141,154.847 350.589,180.786C 346.221,187.242 342.077,193.854 337.527,200.184C 336.703,201.33 335.624,202.27 334.672,203.313C 333.72,204.355 332.524,205.219 331.817,206.441C 321.519,224.255 308.804,240.594 298.457,258.379C 286.183,279.474 273.153,300.121 260.438,320.953C 247.317,342.451 234.983,364.434 223.132,386.657C 218.774,394.83 214.969,403.289 210.643,411.479C 209.909,412.869 209.174,414.26 208.44,415.65C 207.706,417.041 207.387,418.749 206.237,419.822C 202.371,423.428 195.548,420.45 190.385,419.313C 181.181,417.288 172.796,411.822 165.563,405.782C 155.591,397.454 146.73,387.554 139.673,376.645C 138.739,375.201 137.313,374.142 136.133,372.891C 134.954,371.639 133.502,370.597 132.594,369.136C 128.968,363.305 125.303,357.497 121.761,351.615C 119.882,348.495 119.458,343.791 116.168,342.229C 112.062,340.28 107.359,344.973 103.614,347.548C 94.2328,353.997 84.286,359.591 74.8294,365.929C 50.6338,382.147 26.4381,398.364 2.24249,414.581L 1.61674,414.19L 2.24249,0.569702 Z "/>
                                    <Path x:Name="Path_2" Canvas.Left="260.677" Canvas.Top="40.6177" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFF8F8F8" Data="F1 M 626.467,40.6177C 630.002,64.1845 627.798,88.2671 627.75,112.098C 627.667,153.493 627.584,194.889 627.501,236.285C 627.248,362.542 626.994,488.799 626.741,615.056L 261.303,615.056L 260.677,614.43C 265.518,594.615 274.343,575.972 282.154,557.129C 300.25,513.473 321.398,471.097 343.276,429.208C 390.306,339.164 443.671,251.911 504.798,170.774C 527.125,141.137 551.453,112.832 578.025,86.9329C 588.006,77.2045 596.754,66.0243 607.968,57.7476C 614.73,52.757 622.557,48.0565 626.467,40.6177 Z "/>
                                    <Path x:Name="Path_3" Canvas.Left="603.588" Canvas.Top="0.569702" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFF8F8F8" Data="F1 M 626.741,0.569702L 627.366,14.9619L 626.741,15.5877C 626.115,14.9619 625.361,14.4423 624.863,13.7104C 624.211,12.7509 624.17,11.3899 623.338,10.5817C 618.307,5.69745 611.097,3.15491 604.214,1.82117L 603.588,1.19543L 626.741,0.569702 Z "/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Viewbox>
```

the path is displayed at a fraction of the size it actually is :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Path` does have a `Width` and `Height`.  If you are happy with that size, you can just remove the `Canvas` entirely and let the `Viewbox` scale the `Path` directly.

```
<Viewbox x:Name="MyViewBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <Path  .../>
</Viewbox>
```

Alternatively if want some space around the `Path` you can use a more flexible layout element than a `Canvas` like a `Grid`:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="MyViewBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid Margin="4">
        <Path .../>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

The `Grid` will auto-size to the `Path` (unlike the `Canvas`) and then you can add your margin, and then the `Viewbox` will start its scaling.

Comment: The grid idea works really well except it seems to shrin some paths, I've edited my original post showing new code..

Comment: @meds: That's a different example using multiple paths.  Your original example was with one path.  To use two paths in one grid they have to line up exactly or you have to adjust them individually using their own margins.  The canvas coordinates no longer apply.

Comment: @Rick-Sladkey Not quite sure I understand, do you mean to say the reason the path is scaled down to a tiny size when I use multiple paths is because they're not lined up? What do you mean by not lined up exactly?

Comment: @meds: If you have multiple paths, they need to be positioned.  Originally you were using a canvas.  If you don't use a canvas, you'll need to use something else, like margins.  But if the whole point is just so you can avoid specifiying width and height, it doesn't seem worth it.